# Mutation of the keys in HashMap causes wrong results

Tags: java, hashmap

in my project I use HashMap in order to store some data, and I've recently discovered that when I mutate the keys of the HashMap, some unexpected wrong results may happen. For Example:

```
HashMap<ArrayList,Integer> a = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList<>();
a.put(list1, 1);
System.out.println(a.containsKey(new ArrayList<>())); // true
list1.add(5);
ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(5);
System.out.println(a.containsKey(list2)); // false
```

Note that both `a.keySet().iterator().next().hashCode() == list2.hashCode()` and `a.keySet().iterator().next().equals(list2)` are true.

I cannot understand why it happens, referring to the fact that the two objects are equal and have the same hash-code. Do anyone know what is the cause of that, and if there is any other similar structure that allows mutation of the keys? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use mutable values as hashmap keys. I thought it says it somewhere in the documentation of HashMap, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: I know I shouldn't (regarding the example I've shown) but I cannot understand the cause (the objects are equal and have the same hash codes) and I'm looking for a similar structure that allows that.

Comment: "...if there is any other similar structure that allows mutation of the keys?" - Keys (at least the parts that form the key) are never meant to be mutable since that would defy their use. Think of it in terms of a real world key: if you change your key it won't open the lock anymore. If you change the lock you need a new key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mutable keys are always a problem. Keys are to be considered mutable if the mutation could change their hashcode and/or the result of `equals()`. That being said, lists often generate their hashcodes and check equality based on their elements so they almost never are good candidates for map keys.

What is the problem in your example? When the key is added it is an empty list and thus produces a different hashcode than when it contains an element. Hence even though the hashcode of the key and `list2` are the same *after* changing the key list you'll not find the element. Why? Simply because the map looks in the wrong bucket.

Example (simplified):

Let's start with a few assumptions:

- an empty list returns a hashcode of 0
- if the list contains the element 5 it returns the hashcode 5
- our map has 16 buckets (default)
- the bucket index is determined by hashcode % 16 (the number of our buckets)

If you now add the empty list it gets inserted into bucket 0 due to its hashcode.

When you do the lookup with `list1` it will look in bucket 5 due to the hashcode of 5. Since that bucket is empty nothing will be found.

The problem is that your key list changes its hashcode and thus should be put into a different bucket but the map doesn't know this should happen (and doing so would probably cause a bunch of other problems).

Answer (score 4):

According to the javadocs for [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map
>   keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object
>   is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the
>   object is a key in the map. A special case of this prohibition is that
>   it is not permissible for a map to contain itself as a key. While it
>   is permissible for a map to contain itself as a value, extreme caution
>   is advised: the equals and hashCode methods are no longer well defined
>   on such a map.

Your lists are the keys and you're changing them.  It would not be a problem *if the contents of the list were not* what determine the values for hash code and what is equal, however that is not your case.  If you think about it, it doesn't make much sense to change the key of a map.  The key is what identifies the value, and if that key changes, all bets are off.

The map inserts the value given the hash code upon insertion.  When you search for it later, it uses the hash code  of the parameter to determine if it is a hit.  I think you'd find that had you inserted `list1` with the value already inserted that you would see "true" printed out since `list2.hashCode()` would produce the same hash code as `list1` when it was inserted.

Answer (score 1):

That's because a HashMap uses the `hashCode()` Method of Object in combination with `equals(Object obj)` to check if this map contains an object.

See:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(1);
System.out.println(a.hashCode());
a.add(2);
System.out.println(a.hashCode());
```

This example shows, that the hashCode of your ArrayList has changed.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thanks. Do you know if there is a similar data structure that allows key mutation?

Comment: @RanSch Maybe [`IdentityHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) is right for you?

Comment: @Thomas No, because I need the "equals" checking, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You should never use a mutable object as a key in your hashmap.**

So what basically going on when u put the list1 as key in line 3 is that the map calculates its hashCode which it would later compare in containsKey(someKey) .
but when u mutated the list1 in line 5 its hashCode is essentially changed.
so if u now do

```
System.out.println(a.containsKey(list1));
```

after line 5 it would say `false`
and if u do `System.out.println(a.get(list1));`

it would say `null` as its comparing two different hashCodes

Answer (score -2):

Probably you didn't override equals() and hashCode() methods.

Comment: They are implemented.